# Carousel with setInterval

Tags: javascript, scope, this, carousel, setinterval

in my particular code, i am making a carousel... The arrow functions work and correctly cancel out the interval so no functions have an error but the setInterval to make a default rotation leads to an error. as long as a click is made on the arrows, the slide being presented will change and the interval is correctly cleared (preventing error) and resets it during the focus(), however on a default basis without clicks, instead of autosliding every 3 seconds it will in the console is an error saying this.unfocus is not a function... however the click eventListeners correctly execute that function... is there a scope issue with setInterval and this.goRight --> this.unfocus? im not sure how to fix this error, or what is causing it. all help is appreciated :D

```
class Carousel {
    constructor(element) {
        this.element = element;
        this.slide = this.element.querySelectorAll('.Carousel__item');
        this.left = this.element.querySelector('.Carousel__arrow-left');
        this.left.addEventListener('click', () => { this.goLeft() });
        this.right = this.element.querySelector('.Carousel__arrow-right');
        this.right.addEventListener('click', () => { this.goRight() });
        this.current = 0;
        this.focus();
    }

    unfocus() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
        this.slide[this.current].classList.remove('Carousel__item-focused')
    }

    focus() {
        this.slide[this.current].classList.add('Carousel__item-focused')
        this.interval = setInterval(this.goRight, 3000);
    }

    goLeft() {
        this.unfocus();
        this.current = ((this.current + 2) % 3);
        this.focus();
    }

    goRight() {
        this.unfocus();
        this.current = ((this.current + 1) % 3);
        this.focus();
    }
}

let carousels = document.querySelectorAll(".Carousel");
carousels = Array.from(carousels).map(carousel => new Carousel(carousel));
```

Comment: can you post relevant html?, like `.Carousel` and `.Carousel__item`, etc

Comment: Im not sure, but try to pass el as argument, like this: `goLeft(el) {
        el.unfocus();
        el.current = ((el.current + 2) % 3);
        el.focus();
    }`, and into your `constructor`, let carousel = this; and within the `click` event, `just pass carousel.getLeft(carousel);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try binding context to your callback function:

`setInterval(this.goRight.bind(this), 3000);`

This way, once the callback is called `this` will properly reference the instance of your class.

Cheers.